# Is it possible to save a less session and return to where you've left a mark?

Tags: terminal, less, lubuntu, lxqt

I'm reading through the man page and so far the only thing I can find is `--save-marks` which doesn't save both my reading mark and session when I open up my pdf file in less again, this is my first week so I know little to nothing about this application.

Comment: You can use `screen` to create virtual session, then leave the session. And return when you want.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Hi Romeo I tried screen this morning and had a few test sessions saved but I can't seem to find them anymore, I actually wanted to delete them at some point in time but had no idea what directory screen was saving them in is it possible that an error occurred or was I supposed to use a command before exiting screen?  Also could you point me to the path that houses the sessions? I assumed it was /run/screen/my-username but feeling unsure my OS is lubuntu LXQT

Comment: Here is sample manual with first steps with `screen`. : https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/

Comment: Great site thanks!